# Blending two overlapping DEMs using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem

I have two point clouds with X,Y,Z which have been converted to DEM's.
One is more accurate than the other.

The point at which they overlap (just a 100m strip) however is very uneven.
Is there a way I can make it blend better, I have tried using focal stats but it still isn't enough.

Is there any other method I could use?

Here's a picture of the "unblended" DEM merged. I am wanting a better blend

[image]